# run an ssrs report using excel vba and save as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, reporting-services

I need to run and save several hundred invoices for an audit.

The invoices are generated using SSRS.

Is there a way from excel to have a column of invoice numbers and automate the running of the SSRS invoice report for each invoice number and save it as a pdf???

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, you can pass a parameter to the URL of a SSRS report and render directly as a pdf

Comment: Do you have example vba code how to do this?

Comment: if you have enterprise version , setup a data driven subscription for the report.. it will spit the pdf in minutes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the pdfs from Excel, you can use a function `HYPERLINK` to turn the string into a hyperlink.

The part `&rs:Format=PDF` will save the report directly to a pdf.

`=HYPERLINK("http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/YourFolder%2fInvoice+Report&rs:Format=PDF&InvoiceNumber=" & A2)`

[image]

- if there are any report parameters that do not have a default, they must be passed in.